# send pointer from a class1() to class2() in c#

Tags: c#

I have a class and created a node in it.I want to send address of the node to a function in class2() in c#.
Class Node in Class1() different to Class Node in Class2(). I want to nodes in Class2() are pointing to nodes in Class1().
Please help.

```
public class Class1()
{
   public class Node
    {
        public int x=0, y=0, cost=0;
        public Node up=null, left=null, down=null, right=null, parent=null;
    }
  private Node root=null;
  class2 p=new class2();
  public void function1()
    {
        var tree = new Node();
        root = tree;
        p.function2(root);
    }
}
///////////////////////////////////
public class Class2()
{
public class Node
    {
        public object NodeContent;
        public Node Next;
    }

public void function2(root)
    {
..............................
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to have done it successfully right there.  What problems are you having with the code that you've already written?

Comment: Since your Node is a class, you're already passing it my reference.  Of course, this won't work in your example because Node is defined in two different areas, and as far as .NET is concerned, they are two different definitions and are not compatible: Class1.Node and Class2.Node are different.

Answer (score 6):

You've created two separate `Node` classes when you should only have one.  Having two different classes, with the same name, and the same members, but defined in two different places, results in two different types, and those types aren't interchangeable.

You should have *one* `Node` class, that you define in *one* place, and reference from both of your other classes.

```
public class Node
{
    public object NodeContent;
    public Node Next;
}
public class Class1
{
    Class2 p = new Class2();
    private Node root;
    public void function1()
    {
        var tree = new Node();
        root = tree;
        p.function2(root);
    }
}
public class Class2
{
    public void function2(Node root)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time for my question. But i must asked better my question.